# How to create an inline table from an existing table

Tags: qliksense

I have a table in qlik Sense  loaded from the database.

Example:

| ID | FRUIT | VEG | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |  | 5 |
| 2 | Figs |  | 10 |
| 3 |  | Carrots | 20 |
| 4 | Oranges |  | 12 |
| 5 |  | Corn | 10 |

From this I need to make a filter that will display all the Fruit/Veg records along with records from other joined tables, when selected.

The filter needs to be something like this :

```
|FRUIT_XXX|
|VEG_XXX  |
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you show the desired output, based on the given input, your question might be clearer...   (What is `XXX` in your "something like" thing ?)

Comment: When I select the FRUIT_XXX I want all the FRUIT records and the metrics like count:
So output would be :

ID TYPE COUNT
1 Apple 5
2 Figs 10
4 Oranges 12

Comment: Please use [edit] to add extra info to your question (in a correct formatted way, because data in a comment cannot be formatted)

Comment: Im i right in thinking that your need is to be able to select values from `FRUIT` and `VEG` columns but from a single filter? For example select `Apple` and `Carrot` and this will select only rows with `ID` = `1` and `3`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Currently they are in two different fields. I want to dynamically create a new table with 2 fields  to store the  ID and the  value 'FRUIT' or 'VEG'   or  Is there a way that I can add a new field to the original table in the auto generated section and populated it with 'F' and 'V' based on the fields FRUIT and VEG if they are null or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its possible to be dynamic. Usually I solve these by creating a new field that combines the values from both fields into one field

```
RawData:
Load * Inline [
ID , FRUIT   ,VEG     , COUNT
1  , Apple   ,        , 5
2  , Figs    ,        , 10
3  ,         ,Carrots , 20
4  , Oranges ,        , 12
5  ,         ,Corn    , 10
];

Combined:
Load
  ID,
  'FRUIT_' & FRUIT as Combined
Resident
  RawData
Where
  FRUIT <> ''
;

Concatenate

Load
  ID,
  'VEG_' & VEG as Combined
Resident
  RawData
Where
  VEG <> ''  
;
```

This will create new table (`Combined`) which will be linked to the main table by `ID` field:

[image: Tables]

The new `Combined` field will have the values like this:

[image: Field values]

And the UI:

[image: Result]

P.S. If further processing is needed you can join the `Combined` table to the `RawData` table. This way the `Combined` field will become part of the `RawData` table. To achieve this just extend the script a bit:

```
join (RawData)
Load * Resident Combined;

Drop Table Combined;
```

Comment: thanks Stefan. That is what i was looking for except that the tables are from the oracle database.

Comment: You'll have to change the table and field names to match your data model but apart from that there is no much difference where the data is coming from

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to do it in qlicksense, but in SQL it's like this:

```sql
SELECT 
   ID
   CASE WHEN FRUIT IS NULL THEN VEG ELSE FRUIT END as FruitOrVeg,
   COUNT
FROM tablename
```

Comment: Thankd Luuk, but the problem is  i don't have the privileges to alter or create  tables in the database.

Answer (score 0):

To do this dynamically, you should use the `CrossTable()` function. This will allow you to pivot your table such that *n* number of columns "pivot" into just 2 columns, one for the column name and one for the column value.

Here's the script you could use to achieve this:

```
// STEP 1

[Original]:
Load * Inline [
ID  ,   FRUIT   ,   VEG     ,   COUNT
1   ,   Apple   ,           ,   5
2   ,   Figs    ,           ,   10
3   ,           ,   Carrots ,   20
4   ,   Oranges ,           ,   12
5   ,           ,   Corn    ,   10
];

// STEP 2.

Rename Field [ID] to [ID old];
Rename Field [COUNT] to [COUNT old];

[Reordered]:
NoConcatenate Load
    [ID old] as [ID]
  , [COUNT old] as [COUNT]
  , *
Resident [Original];

Drop Table [Original];
Drop Fields [ID old], [COUNT old];

// STEP 3.

[Dynamic]:
CrossTable ([Type], [Item], 2)
Load *
Resident [Reordered];

Drop Table [Reordered];

// STEP 4.

[Combined]:
Load
    [ID]
  , [COUNT]
  , [Type]
  , [Item]
  , [Type] & '_' & [Item] as [Full Item]
Resident [Dynamic]
  Where Not IsNull(EmptyIsNull([Item]))
;

Drop Table [Dynamic];
```

Here's how it works:

`STEP 1.`: Load the data from Oracle DB. You can add new food categories as columns as needed.

`STEP 2.`: We are assuming that we may dynamically load in new food categories, but not other types of new columns like "Price" or things like that. In order to get the dynamic part to work in Qlik, we will use the `CrossTable()` function in the next step. That function requires fields to be in order of "regular" fields that stay put, followed by "food category" fields that will be pivoted. As such, we are going to ensure that our two "regular" columns are ordered first. To achieve this, we simply rename them temporarily using the `Rename Field` keywords and then loading them first in our `[Reordered]` table, making sure that we alias them back to their original field names. This allows us to use the asterisk `*`, which will load all other fields after those ones. This makes it so that you can load as many food category fields as you want in the future -- we'll always load the them after our "regular" fields.

`STEP 3.`: Here we use the `CrossTable ([Type], [Item], 2)` function, which is saying "after the first 2 fields, pivot the remaining fields such that the column names ("FRUIT", "VEG") go into a newly generated `[Type]` field and all of the column values ("Apple", "Figs", "Carrots", "Corn") go into another newly generated field called `[Item]`.

`STEP 4.`: Finally, we can combine our `[Type]` and `[Item]` fields into a new `[Full Item]` field to get the result you desire. We use the ampersand `&` operator to concatenate the fields values together. Our `Where` clause, `Where Not IsNull(EmptyIsNull([Item]))`, is saying "return records where `[Item]` is not `null`, and empty values are to be considered `null` in this case."

This is what your result should look like:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense table results]

Then if you wanted to add new food category fields in the future, like dairy, your load script is fully dynamic and will correctly handle those new records and columns:

```
[Original Plus Dairy]:
Load * Inline [
ID  ,   FRUIT   ,   VEG     ,   DAIRY   ,   COUNT
1   ,   Apple   ,           ,           ,   5
2   ,   Figs    ,           ,           ,   10
3   ,           ,   Carrots ,           ,   20
4   ,   Oranges ,           ,           ,   12
5   ,           ,   Corn    ,           ,   10
6   ,           ,           ,   Milk    ,   31
7   ,           ,           ,   Cheese  ,   19
8   ,           ,           ,   Yogurt  ,   13
];
```

[image: Another Qlik Sense screenshot of table results]

Also, if you still want to keep your original `[FRUIT]` and `[VEG]` fields, you can just delete or comment out the `Drop Table [Reordered];` line from my example script above.